# Can we associate our Programmers account to our StackOverflow Careers CV?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I was messing around with my CV in StackOverflow Careers and I noticed that I can associate my SO, Meta SO, SU, and SF accounts to my CV. I didn't see an option for Programmers so I figured it isn't allowed yet.

Will this feature be allowed in the future?

**Some thoughts**: Honestly, I'm a bit skeptical about it because of the issues we're having with off-topic questions right now. It's hard to measure the accuracy of the reputation here because of that.

Comment: Probably you get an answer on http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Thanks. I'll post this question there.

Answer (score 2):

[Stack Overflow Careers 2.0](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) allows you to associate any open Stack Exchange site with your profile.

- More info: [Careers 2.0 Launches](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/careers-2-0-launches/)